# Query child records for a left-joined query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, query-builder

I have four tables,
quiz_headers, quizzes, questions and answers tables.

I want to join Quizzes and Questions table with each question having related answers in relationship.

So I can access something like @foreach ($quizzes->question->answers as $answer).

I've quiz_header_id in quizzes table:

I select all the quiz records based on quiz_header_id from quizzes table.

I leftjoin this query to questions table on question_id.

```
    $usersResults = DB::table('quizzes')
    ->where('quiz_header_id','=',$userQuizDetails->id)
    ->leftJoin('questions', 'quizzes.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    ->get();
```

I want to get child records from answers table with this query for every question.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQx49.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La0z3.png)

Comment: what is the foreign key name in answers table for `questions` and `answers` relationship?